# Why I=(V(in)-V(out))/R in zener resistor circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

I am a hobbyist electronics student who try to study "The art of electronics" book. I am having trouble understanding below passage from the book?

[image]

I am having trouble following what is going on with I = (Vin-Vout) / R part? How do we get that result?

Comment: The formula is giving the input current, not the output current.

Comment: @efox29 upvotes aren't a mean to counter downvotes, it's already been discussed on meta. upvote should mean that a question a) shows research effort, b) is potentially useful to other people who have made a research effort themselves first.

Comment: @vaxquis I normally upvote questions that are relevant to my interests. However, even though that this was not a question I would upvote myself, I feel that the question (at the time) was downvoted for no good reason. OP had a question, provided an image and reference to the source of his question, and indicated that they do not understand why an equation was what it was. I upvoted because it had those things, and it was to balance out an unnecessary downvote.

Comment: @efox29 Either you're voting basing solely on question's merits or you're casting a troll vote. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes , quote from the answer accepted as the meta consensus : `Effectively, when you cast a "cancelling vote", what you're saying is "I don't feel strongly about this question/answer, but my half-hearted opinion is worth more than the genuine opinion of the person who cast the first vote". **How incredibly arrogant!**` - emphasis mine. Please read the meta consensus before indulging in further discussion about this.

Comment: NB the fact that somebody doesn't understand a handbook doesn't show research effort. Even using a digital camera to get a shot of the book you don't understand is not "research effort" by itself. Research is `creative work undertaken on a systematic basis in order to increase the stock of knowledge` - I hardly find any creative work nor systematic base in OPs case. He hasn't even stated *what is his particular difficulty here!* Not knowing Ohm's is another thing - he does show a desire to increase knowledge, though, but that doesn't necessarily mean the question is good or useful by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of ideal diodes as letting through however much current is needed in order to keep the voltage down to a certain level.  In this case, a zener is chosen that wants to keep the voltage across it to the desired value for `Vout`.  So how much current does it need to allow through in order to maintain that voltage?

There's only one place for current to go, so whatever flows through the zener also flows through the resistor.  When you first apply power to `Vin`, `Vout` will be equal to `Vin`.  This is higher than the zener's breakdown voltage, so it starts letting current through.

As the current increases, `Vout` goes down, because the voltage drop across the resistor gets higher.  When `Vout` gets down to the zener's breakdown voltage, the zener stops letting more current through. At that point, the voltage drop across the resistor is `Vin - Vout`, and we know the resistor's resistance, so we can calculate the current through the resistor using Ohm's law as `(Vin - Vout) / R`.  Again, we know the same current flows through the zener because it has nowhere else to go.

Answer (score 6):

The input to your "regulator circuit" is Vin - any problems with that?

The output from your regulator circuit is Vout (Vzener) - any problems here?

So, this MUST mean that the current thru the resistor is: -

\$ \dfrac{V_{IN} - V_{OUT}}{R}\$

It's ohms law - voltage across the resistor divided by its resistance equals current thru the resistor.

That is the current that always flows into the resistor from the input voltage. It will also be the current flowing into the zener when you have no load connected to Vout.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the zener to go into zener breakdown (which is the region you want to be in), the current through it needs to be kept within a certain range.

The knee current (Izk) is the point in which zener breakdown begins. Typically you would want to operate in a region somewhere past Izk, and the datasheet for the zener usually specifies a test current (Izt).

Knowing Izt (which is something you should know before hand), you can then calculate the required R needed to ensure that the current through the zener is kept at that value.

For your circuit, its the formula you presented because there is no load. If there was a load present, then you have to consider the load current as well as the zener current which would then change the value of the required R.

Comment: The formula is ohm's law. It doesn't depend on the zener diode being in breakdown, or not in breakdown. If Vin and Vout are as stated, then the current through the resistor will be equal to the voltage drop divided by the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the Ohm's law applied to the resistor, your circuit only has one loop so the current in the resistor will be the same in the zener.

Comment: So, am I supposed to assume that zener has no resistance?

Comment: No, but you can suppose a resistance for the zener equal to Vout/I. But if these values change the resistance will change too.
@yasar

Comment: Better to assume that 'resistance' of a diode is not a useful concept as the current it passes is in general not proportional to the voltage across it.

Comment: @yasar there is more going on inside a diode than basic resistance.  In this case, the diode (ideal, and when biased correctly) behaves like a voltage source Vout with zero resistance.